# Custom wordpress meta query (no result)

Tags: php, advanced-custom-fields, wordpress

**Problem**

I am looping through custom post types (Advanced Custom Fields) in Wordpress. I only want to display events with **start_date** equal to $newdate variable, defined in the beginning.

The start_date is in the format YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm (the same as $newdate). $newdate is set to the beginning of the day so I wouldn't exclude events with different hours in the day and compare is set to greater than (just to test the query).

However I am not getting any results.

```
<?php
$newdate = date('Y-m-d 00:00');
//<-- Start the Loop. -->!
$args = array( 
        'post_type' => 'epsa_events', 
        'posts_per_page' => 5,
        'orderby' => 'meta_value',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'meta_query' => array (
            array(
            'key' => 'start_time',
            'value'   => $newdate,
            'compare' => '>=',
            'type' => 'datetime' 
            )
        )
    );

$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: if your  start_time is in that format then it is not datetime but varchar.So you compare 2 string with uncontrollable results.

Comment: What time format do you suggest

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:-

```
'meta_key'   =>  'event-start-date',
'meta_query' => array (
            array(
            'key' => 'start_time',
            'value' => date('Ymd',strtotime($newdate)),
            'compare' => '>=',
            'type' => 'date' 
            )
        )
```

Comment: Stull no results with this change.

Comment: change type datetime to date

Comment: Did you ever get this working, im trying to filter datetime by a range of hours as well, but not having any luck @rmilosic

Comment: @NickeyK sorry, It was quite a long time ago and I can't seem to find the source code unfortunately :/

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have some small mistakes here.

First, if you use `'orderby' => 'meta_value'` you must add a `'meta_key' => KEYVALUE` to your `$args` where `KEYVALUE` is the name of the custom field you want to use for sorting. Check `WP_Query` documentation on [Order & Orderby Parameters](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters).

Second, **assuming your `start_date` field type is *Date Time Picker***, if you want to get all events that already started you're using the wrong comparison operator. So assuming you also want to sort by date, your `$args` code should be:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'epsa_events',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'orderby'        => 'meta_value',
    'order'          => 'ASC',
    'meta_key'       => 'start_time',
    'meta_type'      => 'DATETIME'
    'meta_query'     => array (
        array(
            'key'     => 'start_time',
            'compare' => '<=',
            'value'   => $newdate,
            'type'    => 'DATETIME'
        )
    )
);
```

Take a look at *Date Time Picker* [documentation](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/date-time-picker/) too.

I hope this helps!